# Зафиксировать столбцы таблицы

Tags: javascript, css

Вывожу из бд тиблицу, в таком формате

```
 echo("<table class='b-tableProjects'>".
    "<th class='b-tableProjects__ColCap'>Тип объекта</th>
     <th class='b-tableProjects__ColCap'>Вид объекта</th>
     <th class='b-tableProjects__ColCap'>Код проекта</th>
     <th class='b-tableProjects__ColCap'>Рабочее название</th>
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result_set, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
     echo("<td class='b-tableProjects__Col'>".$row['project_type']."</td>".
          "<td class='b-tableProjects__Col'>".$row['object_type']."</td>".
          "<td class='b-tableProjects__Col b-tableProjects__projectNumber'>".$row['project_number']."</td>".
          "<td class='b-tableProjects__Col'>".$row['work_name']."</td>");
      }
   echo("</table>");
```

Не силен в css подскажите как зафиксировать при прокрутке столбцы?
Пробовал `position:fixed` для tr, фиксируются значения а не сам столбец.

Comment: Табличка строится по строкам, Вам нужно зафиксировать именно колонку?

Comment: Да, пытаюсь сделать аналог экселя

Comment: http://demo.umi-cms.spb.su/demos/tableFixCol/1.html